# Post data with field in django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am designing my API using `serializers.ModelSerializer` and `viewsets.ModelViewSet`. I can post the `foreignKey` value using the `id`, but I want to post it using the `name`. Here is an example of what I mean:

I can post on this:

```
curl --request POST \
     --url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book/ \
     --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
     --form author=1 \
     --form name=MY_BOOK
```

but I want do this:

```
curl --request POST \
     --url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book/ \
     --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
     --form author=AUTHOR_NAME \
     --form name=MY_BOOK
```

I have try use `to_internal_value` it's work, but I think it want to know is there a better plan：

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.copy()
        data['author'] = get_object_or_404(Author, name=data['author']).id
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Here in my code:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
    fields = '__all__'

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.copy()
        data['author'] = get_object_or_404(Author, name=data['author']).id
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Any help or explanation is welcome! Thank you.

Comment: Where are you using the custom `to_internal_value(...)` method?

Comment: Hi @JPG thanks for your help, I have edit my code, I using to_internal_value in BookSerializer.

Comment: This looks fine to me, and I would've done the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield). Define `BookSerializer` like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", queryset=Author.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```